# Django-Cms and Django-shop migration issues

Tags: python, django, django-cms, django-migrations, django-shop

I started creating my website on my own PC using the Django-cms install script then I tried to add a lot of applications such as Django-Helpdesk and others and everything was smooth until I tried to add pieces of djangoSHOP demo project and dependencies to email_auth.

Then I started to have report that the migration history was inconsistent and migrations applied out of order.

Before adding djangoShop to the installed apps, I just add the following commands to setup the DB:

```
manage.py migrate --run-syncdb --noinput
manage.py migrate --noinput
```

and everything was ok.

Now, as I'm just starting, I don't have changes to the schema to apply but most of the django apps I try to install have migrations folders with several migrations.

I don't want to update an existing schema, I want to create a new one.

I'm working from a blank database so do I really need to apply all those migrations ? To me it seems that the default behaviour of running migrations is not compatible with starting from a blank db,
I don't understand what to do just initialise the database to just have the required tables created.

Did anyone got the same kind of problems?
How did you fixed it?

Edit:

```
django-cms>=3.5,<3.6
Django 1.11.19
```

> Error message:
>
> Django InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration Helpdesk.000xxxxx.py is applied before its dependency email_auth.0001_initial.py on database 'default'

Comment: What versions of django/django-cms etc are you using? What is the error you're getting? If it's an inconsistency with django content types then that's a bug in the latest version of CMS. Drop back a minor version to fix it.

Comment: Ok, so what is `email_auth` and which helpdesk migration? Exactly what is in the `dependencies` list for `email_auth.0001_initial.py`? Your error doesn't match any of the migrations in django-helpdesk; https://github.com/django-helpdesk/django-helpdesk/tree/master/helpdesk/migrations

Comment: @markwalker_ Hi, thank you for your help. email_auth is an app packaged by djangoShop to allow users to authenticate with an email and a password instead of a regular user name. I think that in some ways all apps that handle user objects are impacted by this app. The fact that I try to install these in a docker container is an added difficulty as I try to delete the migrations and recreate them. My process is to pip install requirements, add all I need in settings.py collectstatic, migrate and run.